# How to check user is "logged in"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using form authentication with below method in my ASP.NET application

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text, true);
```

How do I check whether user is logged in or not? And how can I get the user name of a logged in user?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

I managed to find the correct one. It is below.

```
bool val1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

**EDIT**

The credit of this edit goes to [@Gianpiero Caretti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086529/how-to-check-user-is-logged-in#comment24261976_6086652) who suggested this in comment.

```
bool val1 = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: Just a little fix for safer code: bool val1 = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: In newer versions of C#, you can use `User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true`.

Comment: or `User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?? false`, but @bradlis7's code is probably easier to read.

Comment: or `(User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated).GetValueOrDefault()`

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) ...
```

Comment: It is the same as `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Answer (score 15):

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Page.Title = "Home page for " + User.Identity.Name;
}
else
{
    Page.Title = "Home page for guest user.";
}
```

Comment: Seeing that this approach doesn't have that many upvotes, are there any drawbacks / issues to watch out for when using this approach? Ive decided to use this and it seems to work, so far.

Comment: It's almost the same as the top voted answer but we are not using namespaces here

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way to check if they are authenticated is `Request.User.IsAuthenticated` I think (from memory)

Comment: well "Request.LogonUserIdentity" class gives all these methods and properties. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No @beardtwizzle. This is showing the windows account logged in or not. Even if your cookies removed you can see the user name of window account and login. This one worked for me. "bool val1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated"