# How to check if user is logged in

Tags: asp.net

I have created a Login page where users must provide username and password to have access to some specific resources, where they can upload images, or just edit some description about themselves.
My web.config file looks like this:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Secure/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

<location path="Secure">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

So when the user has typed in the username and pw, he is redirected to the index.aspx page.
Depending wether the user is logged in or not, the index.aspx should show or hide some stuff.
This is how I check if he is logged in:

```
bool isLoggedIn = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;  
    if (isLoggedIn) 
    {
        placeHolder2.Visible = true;
        ...
    }
```

Now the problem is that the: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; ALWAYS returns true, so unauthorised people will be seeing the stuff that should be hidden.

I am not sure about the: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
I just googled "How to check if user is logged in", and suggestions were the: 
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

I want only the people that are logged in to view the private stuff. How do I go about this? How do I make the: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated only return true when the user is logged in?
Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086529/how-to-check-user-is-logged-in-in-asp-net-c

Comment: I've seen that thread, but it doesn't help me solve my problem

Comment: Is HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated true for anonymous user too?

Answer (score 8):

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {.....}
```

edit based on some comments
Authenticated via "Forms", check here

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`    //  will be "Forms" if using forms based auth
                                                 // "Negotiate" is using windows integrated
                                                  // etc

If using .net 4.5 and you wanted "SET" user claims. 
The [ClaimsPrincipal is recommended reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.current)

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` are same. In other words, according to OP, using `Request.IsAuthenticated` won't make different because it will also return true.

Comment: The: Request.IsAuthenticated gives the desired behavior, but the to above doesn't. Those were the ones that I already tried. And thanks, it works with: Request.IsAuthenticated

Comment: I was wrong, it didnt fix it, still the same problem. So far I found out why it returns true, even if the user has not logged in. The: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns the name on my computer (host address/name). Why is that so? I should instead check if the user has logged in with username and password

Answer (score 3):

`bool isLoggedIn = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Answer (score 1):

My coding is

```
bool val1 = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) &&
    (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) &&
    (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType.ToString() == "Forms");
```

for identifying the users with domain login and logged in form