# Is there a possibility to set a variable in endpoint in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCategoriesWithImagesAsync()
{
    var result = _categoryService.GetCategoriesWithImagesAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Here I'd like to add something like `Authorize`, and return more data if user is logged in. Is it possible?

EDIT!
I'm using JWT to check if user is logged in.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I understand both your questions but fail to get the relation between them. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Btw, not sure if `Ok()` accepts a `Task` as parameter.

Comment: You can check claims for current user or try resolving `IAuthorizationService` and implement  needed stuff from there in the body of action.

Comment: yeah :D my fault, incorrect method name, hah.

To be more specific: if user is not logged in I want to return categories with data, if user is logged in return category without data (only header is filled). I don't want to send. I don't want to send a bool variable, I want to detect it somehow.

Comment: To detect if a user is logged in should be fairly easy. Also to see its claims/roles. For the authentication part maybe this helps. On my mobile so I cant check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006283/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in

Comment: from ASP.NET 5 there is no System.Web.HttpContext.Current :/

Comment: `userManager.GetUserAsync() != null`

Comment: @Pieterjan I don't get it, what do you mean?

Comment: @Stefan
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetCategoriesWithImagesAsync()
    {
        Request.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        var result = _categoryService.GetCategoriesWithImages();
        return Ok(result);
    }
Is it ok?

Comment: I think @Pieterjan's answer would be better

Comment: Ah `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` that's the one I was looking for...

Comment: ok, but it's always false

Comment: my fault again :D I forgot to send token from angular to API, now I can detect this, thanks a lot :P

Answer (score 1):

The `AuthorizeAttribute` will always block execution of the controller method if unauthorized.

What you can do is, if you're using Identity that is, inject the `UserManager` and call `GetUserAsync` to check if the user is signed in.

```
[Controller]
[Route("api/V1")]
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser<Guid>> userManager;
    public CategoryController(UserManager<IdentityUser<Guid>> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategoriesWithImagesAsync()
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```